# Using dynamic refs in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I have searched in SO and vue3 docs about dynamic refs. I need them. I did the next, but the refs are undefined in the console.log. What am I doing wrong?

```
    // code into a modal dialog
    <div v-for="index in 2" :key="index">
        <q-btn @click="test()">teste</q-btn>
        <textarea
        :ref="`(el) => (messageRef[index] = el)`">
     </textarea>   
    </div>                      
    
    // setup
    const messageRef = ref({});
    
    function test(){
        const ref1=messageRef[1].value
        console.log(ref1)
        const ref2=messageRef[2].value
        console.log(ref2)
    }
   return {test, messageRef}
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the Vue 3 documentation on how template refs work, specifically the section [Refs inside `v-for`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for).  The correct syntax is much simpler than you think, it's just: `ref="messageRef"`.

You also need a few more corrections, like `messageRef` should be initialized as an array, not an object.

```js
const messageRef = ref([]);
```

You also have some issues trying to access the textarea value:

- index of a ref array should be accessed *after* the `.value` of the [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)
- The ref value is the DOM element, so then you need to access the `.value` of the textarea element.

All together the correct syntax is:

```js
const ref1 = messageRef.value[0].value
```

[demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)